# Is this theorem the same as uniform limit theorem, and why does my proof seems to be wrong, am I misunderstanding the notation?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence

> Suppose $f_n→f$ uniformly, with $f_n$ continuous for all $n$. Then $f_n(x)\to f(x_0)$ as $x\to x_0$

This is the theorem I got from [notes](https://myweb.uiowa.edu/pbreheny/7110/f22/notes/8-24.pdf)

My key attempt to show this question is as follows:

$$\lvert f_n(x)-f(x_0)\rvert\leq |f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|+|f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$$

$|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ by continuity of $f_n$ for all $n$

$|f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ by uniform convergence of $f_n\to f$

---

**However, I have seen a similar theorem called the uniform limit theorem and the proof is also different by using three times the absolute value difference. Capture is below**

[image]

*Question 1* **I figured out that what we are proving is different, and I am confused are those two theorems exactly the same theorem and have no subtle difference?**

*Question 2*   **Am I misunderstanding the final step saying**. Much appreciate it if someone could write $f_n(x)\to f(x_0)$ as $x\to x_0$ in terms of some limit equation.

Much appreciate your help

Comment: The problem is with $|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ by continuity of $f_n$ for all $n$. How close $x$ has to be to $x_0$ varies with $n$ so your proof does not work.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for your reply. Is the final claim $f_n(x)\to f(x_0)$ as $x\to x_0$ should be $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) =f(x_0)$

Comment: @geetha290krm Sorry for bothering again. Would you please check out this one? If written in this way, could it be valid by any chance $|f_n(x)-f(x_0)|\leq |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(x_0)|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two possible interpretations of "$f_n(x)\to f(x_0)$ as $x\to x_0$":
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(x_0) \tag{1}
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{x\to x_0} f_n(x) = f(x_0) \tag{2}
$$
Usually "$AAA\to BBB$ as $x\to a$" means something like
$$\lim_{x\to a} CCC=BBB,$$
(where $CCC$ is related to $AAA$)
so $(1)$ is the go-to choice.
Other than that,
note that $(2)$ is obviously true because of the continuity of $f_n$,
so $(2)$ is not worth formulating as a theorem.
Considering that your first line in grey is a theorem, it must mean $(1)$.

Now, back to equation $(1)$ above.
Since $(f_n)$ is convergent, the inner limit equals $f(x)$,
so $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0),
$$
which is equivalent to the continuity of $f$ at $x_0$, i.e. the quoted Theorem 8.2.2.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are the two equations you provided equivalent? I am not sure your quote "interpreting in the second way does not make sense", what second way your are referring to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't see too much difference between $(1)$ and $(2)$ except swapping the limits, as you also said, $(2)$ is true, both are equivalent. Why would you say interpreting as statement $(2)$ does not make sense?

Comment: @LJNG Equation $(1)$ is not trivially true! Try to prove it yourself and you will know. But on the other hand, $(2)$ is trivial. In general, you can't just swap limits. They are _not_ equivalent in general. The fact that they can be equal in this case says something about the nice property of uniform convergence. This is why it becomes a theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Agree with what you said but not sure about the trivial claim.  Hah, I think I sort of get the logic behind this. Please check out.  $(2)$ is basically symbolic of what my first line in grey is in the question, and so it is trivial. We aim to show $(1)$; if we can show that, then the consequence of uniform convergence is the swapping limits is equivalent.

Comment: @LJNG No, your first line in grey is $(1)$. I was quoting $(2)$ because $(2)$ could be a possible misinterpretation, and I'm saying that $(2)$ should not be the correct interpretation of the grey line.

Comment: This is the reason why $(1)$ is the theorem and $(2)$ is not. $(2)$ is too trivial to be formulated as a theorem.

Comment: Updated to improve clarity.

Comment: Is this interpretation make sense? $(1)$ is showing the continuity of $f$, $(2)$is saying the $f_n$ uniform converges at each continuous point. Can inner limit of $(2)$ written as $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0}f_n(x)=f_n(x_0)$? I am not sure about the @geetha290krm in the comment saying, "How close $x$ has to be to $x_0$ varies with $n$"

Comment: geetha290krm is saying that your proof is incorrect. You cannot find $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|<\delta$, then $|f_n(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$, _and_ $\delta$ does not depend on $n$. You should try to formulate what exactly you are trying to prove before proving it. In this case, what you should prove is $(1)$.

Comment: I am sort of curious how you guys can spot out $\delta$ does not depend on $n$ immediately. In my previous wording, such $\delta-\epsilon$ pair may not hold for all $n$. Let's rewind to say for each $n$ we have $\delta_n$ satisfy $|f_n(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$, then I take $min\{\delta_1,\delta_2,\ldots\}$, and this will holds for all $n$. Is this making sense?

Comment: When you see $\forall n \exists \delta \dots$, you know that $\delta$ depends on $n$. Your suggestion would not work because you cannot guarantee there is a minmum in the infinite set $\{\delta_1,\dots\}$. From this you can again see the importance of uniform convergence.